# chrome web extention not showing popup

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, popup

I saw a youtube video of how to create a basic chrome extension and i loaded unpacked extension into the browser successfully but it does't give any popup.Here is the code

```
{
    "name":"Facebook",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"My Facebook Profile",
    "manifest_version":2,
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"google-plus-red-128.png",
        "popup":"hello.html"
    }
}
```

and here is the html file

```
<h2>hello world</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct manifest keyword for a [browser action popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) is `"default_popup"`, not `"popup"`. Change that, and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

chrome apps are script based. all you have here is your manifest file. you need to write some java script and give some conditions for making it happen.

check out this, I think it has what you are looking for:

[Chrome Extension run for a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396634/chrome-extension-run-for-a-specific-page)

Comment: i created the html file as well and when i wrote it in script tag as well its still the same.What i want is when i click on the extension a small popup should show hello world but it does't do anything

Comment: No scripts are necessary here. The manifest (with the correct keys) along with the HTML file are sufficient to make a functioning extension.

Comment: the extension works but its only adding and icon beside the search box and clicking it does no action at all
http://goo.gl/9W4xI